# List of elements

Tags: xpath, selenium, count, element

I have some links at the page like:

```
123test.com/456
abc_test.com/sdfsd
abc_test.org
```

I have to get all elements which href attribute consists of **test** word.

I know how to click at such link by given number:

```
selenium.click("//body/descendant::a[contains(@href,'test')][2]")
```

This code will click at second link which has 'test' in address. But how to get that count of links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function:

```
get_xpath_count(self,xpath)
    """
    Returns the number of nodes that match the specified xpath, eg. "//table" would give
    the number of tables.

    'xpath' is the xpath expression to evaluate. do NOT wrap this expression in a 'count()' function; we will do that for you.
    """
```